# I have a weather window that keeps popping up

Tags: malware

I have a weather window that keeps popping up. It occurs randomly & wants permission to install. Problem is, it looks me out of doing anything but installing. Only way to not install is restart device.

Galaxy note7 w/ current updates

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>